# What was a substitute in jQuery 1.5.1 for today's .attr()

Tags: jquery

I'm modifying an app that uses jQuery 1.5.1 and unfortunately updating jQuery library to most current version in that app is not an option.
I have this script that basically inserts "onlick" attributes into  tags.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var $hyperlinkSelectors = $('a[href$=".pdf"], a[href$=".doc"], a[href$=".docx"], a[href$=".xls"]');

    $hyperlinkSelectors.each(function () {
        var fileExtention = '.' + $(this).attr('href').split('.').pop();
        $(this).attr('onclick', "_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','" + $(this).text() + fileExtention + "','click']);");
    });
});
```

But the problem that I'm having is that jQuery 1.5.1 can't understand or use .attr() function. I've tried .prop() but no luck as well.

What was a substitute in jQuery 1.5.1 for today's .attr() ?

Comment: `$().attr()` has been around since jQuery 1.0. I'm assuming that's not your issue.

Comment: What are your error messages, what doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: Why are you using `$(this).attr('onclick'` instead of `$(this).click()`?

Comment: Hmm.., I've tried adding reference to most current version of jQuery into the same html document and it worked.

Comment: Because i have to insert onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','" + $(this).text() + fileExtention + "','click']);" into <a href=""> tag

Comment: No error messages at all. I'm using Google Chrome console to check for error. But just onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','" + $(this).text() + fileExtention + "','click']);" is not being inserted. It finds those "a" tags if i use $('a[href$=".pdf"], a[href$=".doc"], a[href$=".docx"], a[href$=".xls"]'); but it does not insert onlick attribute for some reason

Comment: Just found out that it gets confused with word "onclick" in .attr(), i renamed word "onclick" to "test" and it worked with "test" but I gotta insert "onclick"

Comment: Please check out mine and @Blazemonger's answers below. You can (and should) achieve this without using the `onclick` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't attach event handlers after the DOM is loaded by using `.attr('onclick')`. The DOM will be altered, but the event won't be run.

Try [`.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) instead:

```
$hyperlinkSelectors.each(function () {
    var fileExtension = '.' + $(this).attr('href').split('.').pop();
    $(this).click(function(e) {
       _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', $(this).text()+fileExtension, 'click']);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try simplifying it to something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href$=".pdf"], a[href$=".doc"], a[href$=".docx"], a[href$=".xls"]').click(function() {
        var $link = $(this);
        var ext = '.' + $link.attr('href').split('.').pop();
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', $link.text() + ext, 'click']);
    });
});
```

Please note that there is no need to use `$().each()` with this approach either, as `.click()` implicitly iterates the collection for you.